# How to store a $_SESSION, Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, session-variables, nsmutableurlrequest, nshttpcookie

Is there any way to catch and store a $_SESSION in Objective-C at all? I know that both session and cookies is extremely intertwined, so is it possible to use NSHTTPCookie to catch it or something? Or is this something i have to handle in the php code and not in my objective-c code to make this work?

I can tell you what i'm trying to do. I'm trying to send some information to a server trough NSMutableURLRequest which is not a problem, and then i'm trying to catch the session that i then would be recieving.

Comment: By "session", do you mean the session cookie, or all data stored in the session?

Comment: Answer on both would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sessions are stored on the server side, so *no data that is stored in the session is available to the client* unless the server chooses to send it in some other way. The only thing that is passed to the client and back is a *session identifier*, which the server uses to locate the correct session when the client sends a request.

The session identifier is usually passed in a cookie, but the name of the cookie will vary by server. PHP often uses `PHPSESSID`, but it's configurable to any name in `php.ini`.

To get all the cookies passed from a server to your app (which will give you the session cookie if it has been set) is to do;

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieStore = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
NSArray *cookies = [cookieStore cookiesForURL:url];
```

...passing in an the NSURL object pointing to the server. This will return an `NSArray` of [`NSHTTPCookie`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookie_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which you can loop through and get the information you want.